# Is it to possible to catch some touch up event on a page, if I hold a finger down before it shows up?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

That is, I hold it down on one page, transition to new page starts and on that new page I want to catch a touch up. I've tried to use PhoneApplicationFrame ManipulationStarted/ManipulationCompleted events, but it doesnt help. ManipulationStarted fires on the first page, but ManipulationCompleted  is never fired on the new page, though I continue to hold a finger down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You please try something similar to this

`Touch.FrameReported += TouchFrameReported;` // register the event in constructor

```
   void TouchFrameReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
    {
      var tp = e.GetPrimaryTouchPoint(Control); // Control you want to manupulate

        switch (tp.Action)
        {
                case TouchAction.Move:
                case  TouchAction.Up:
                case  TouchAction.Down:
         }
      }
```